# How to gradually hide/unhide a group of objects?

Tags: animation, materials, keyframes, groups

I want to gradually hide/unhide a group of objects (ctrl-j). For example, I have 2 nested spheres with a radius=1cm and radius 2cm. Both have different materials. Opportunities I have found so far.

1. Show/hide abruptly with Object Properties/Visibility/Viewports and keyframes. But it only works abruptly. I also tried to change the Bezier transitions in the Graph Editor. But Blender doesn't allow that.
2. Gradual fade in/out with Material/Alpha keyframes of each individual sphere. It works but is cumbersome. What if the grouped object consists of about 100 individual parts?

Is there perhaps a more elegant way?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you render with and without the objects, and use any video editor to generate a fade transition? It will save render time, but only works when camera is not moving

Comment: Unfortunately, that's a bit too cumbersome for me. In addition, the camera also moves partially. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I helped myself with Node Groups. Then you set the keyframe also only on one position.

[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GVrUtmbZeY)